# Gradle build error while importing android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.0

Whenever I try to open any downloaded project in android studio it always gives me error given below

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
15:10:36.821 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=US, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I have tried many setting changes but nothing helped please someone suggest me the solution

Comment: Try to check your global's gradle.properties AND project's gradle.properties. Or attach the content of those files in your question. Or run as admin, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24565491/1074998

Comment: thanx man run as admin solved my issue